# Support Multiselect Attribute in Admin Grid Column without UI

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, multiselect-attribute, grid-layout

I'm extending a Magento 2 module which doesn't use UI. I've added a new column for a custom attribute to the module's Admin grid. However, I'm trying to change the attribute to a multiselect, and I can't find a way to support multiselect without UI.

Here is what I have now:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.locator.grid.columnSet">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="brand" before="status">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Brand</argument>
                    <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">brand</argument>
                    <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-brand</argument>
                    <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-brand</argument>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                    <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Mycompany\StoreLocator\Source\Brand\Options"/>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

This works great so long as I don't use a select attribute, but it breaks with a multiselect attribute. Filtering is also broken for this attribute once it has a comma in the attribute value.

Is there any way to support this without converting the whole form to UI?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up adding a new filter and a new renderer for multiselect.

Updated layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.locator.grid.columnSet">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="brand" before="status">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Brand</argument>
                    <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">brand</argument>
                    <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-brand</argument>
                    <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-brand</argument>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                    <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Mycompany\StoreLocator\Source\GgBrand\Options"/>
                    <!-- start new -->
                    <argument name="filter" xsi:type="string">Mycompany\StoreLocator\Block\Backend\Widget\Grid\Column\Filter\Multiselect</argument>
                    <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">Mycompany\StoreLocator\Block\Backend\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Multiselect</argument>
                    <!-- end new -->
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

New file: `Mycompany\StoreLocator\Block\Backend\Widget\Grid\Column\Filter\Multiselect.php`

```
<?php

namespace Mycompany\StoreLocator\Block\Backend\Widget\Grid\Column\Filter;

class Multiselect extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Filter\Select {
    /**
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function getCondition() {
        if ($this->getValue() === null) {
            return null;
        }

        $conditions = [];
        $values = explode(',', $this->getValue());
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $conditions[] = ['finset' => $value];
        }

        return $conditions;
    }
}
```

New file: `Mycompany\StoreLocator\Block\Backend\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Multiselect.php`

```
<?php

namespace Mycompany\StoreLocator\Block\Backend\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class Multiselect extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
    /**
     * @param DataObject $row
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(DataObject $row)
    {
        $labels = [];
        $values = explode(',', $this->_getValue($row));
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $labels[] = MyAttributeTextLookupFunction($value);
        }

        $renderedValue = implode(', ', $labels);

        if ($this->getColumn()->getEditable()) {
            $result = '<div class="admin__grid-control">';
            $result .= $this->getColumn()->getEditOnly() ? ''
                : '<span class="admin__grid-control-value">' . $renderedValue . '</span>';

            return $result . $this->_getInputValueElement($row) . '</div>' ;
        }
        return $renderedValue;
    }
}
```

Then I just replaced `MyAttributeTextLookupFunction()` with my own code to get the attribute text that I needed for my custom attribute/column.

Comment: Thanks for the filter solution

Answer (score 0):

@Tyler thank you, your solution work fine, I add my rendered if someone need to add magento category as column in newsletter

```
<?php namespace CustomModule\Newsletter\Block\Backend\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class Multiselect extends
\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{

public $categoryList;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context,
    \CustomModule\Newsletter\Model\Config\Source\Category $categoryList,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->categoryList = $categoryList->toOptionArray();
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * @param DataObject $row
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function render(DataObject $row)
{
    $labels = [];
    $values = explode(',', $this->_getValue($row));
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $labels[] = $this->getLabel($value);
    }

    $renderedValue = implode(', ', $labels);

    if ($this->getColumn()->getEditable()) {
        $result = '<div class="admin__grid-control">';
        $result .= $this->getColumn()->getEditOnly() ? ''
            : '<span class="admin__grid-control-value">' . $renderedValue . '</span>';

        return $result . $this->_getInputValueElement($row) . '</div>';
    }
    return $renderedValue;
}

public function getLabel($value)
{
    foreach ($this->categoryList as $category) {
        if ($category['value'] == $value) {
            return $category['label'];
        }
    }
}
}
```